# EPPlus changing style for axis lines

Tags: c#, epplus

I've been trying to manipulate the axes lines for my chart. Been digging through all the properties of the ExcelChart object but I could not find the corresponding property in the object to be able to edit this part.

Can someone point me to the correct property to be able to restyle the axes for both x and y? I've highlighted the axis lines I meant on the figure below

[image: Excel Chart]

EDIT:

I'm trying to simulate the options in the format axis section that allows me to edit the line properties as needed. This is how it looks like in excel where I could change the needed properties I needed for the axis.

[image]

Comment: What is it you want to restyle?

Comment: @VDWWD I was wondering if you could remove the line entirely or at least change the line color. I'm still going to experiment its properties depending on what the client really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the property you want to change, you might not find it exposed via EPP.
Have a look at the underlying chart's XML elements, and see what you need to add into via inspecting a saved spread sheet (from excel).

```
string xlFile = @"c:\temp\epp\epptest.xlsx";
string sheetName = "TestData";
string ChartName = "lineChartTest";

DisplaySheetNode(xlFile, sheetName, ChartName);




    public void DisplaySheetNode(string xlsFile, string sheetname,string sChartName)
    {
        FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(xlsFile);
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {
            var ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetname];
            var drawings = ws.Drawings;
            var chart = (ExcelLineChart)drawings[sChartName];


            var nsm = drawings.NameSpaceManager;
            var nschart = nsm.LookupNamespace("c");
            var nsa = nsm.LookupNamespace("a");
            var doc = chart.ChartXml;


            var node = chart.ChartXml.SelectSingleNode(@"c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx", nsm);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(PrintXMLNode(node));


        }
    }
```

Then insert the XMLNode you need into the chart.

For this one I wanted to insert the text rotation into XAxis of the chart.
You can use the same approach for the YAxis. As the properties will be just about the same.

```
public enum rotation : int
    {

        none,
        r90 = 5400000,
        r270 = -5400000,
        rNeg32 = -1920000
    }


 rotation rot = rotation.r90;

 XmlNamespaceManager nsm = chart.WorkSheet.Drawings.NameSpaceManager;
        XmlDocument doc = chart.ChartXml;

        XmlNode node = chart.ChartXml.SelectSingleNode(@"c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx", nsm);

        XmlNode InsertAfter = chart.ChartXml.SelectSingleNode(@"c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:plotArea/c:catAx/c:tickLblPos", nsm);

        XNamespace c = XNamespace.Get(nsm.LookupNamespace("c")); //  @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart";
        XNamespace a = XNamespace.Get(nsm.LookupNamespace("a")); // @"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main";

        XElement xml = new XElement(c + "txPr", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "c", c),
                            new XElement(a + "bodyPr", new XAttribute("rot", (int)rot), new XAttribute("vert", "horz"),new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "a", a)),
                            new XElement(a + "lstStyle", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "a", a)),
                            new XElement(a + "p", new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "a", a),
                                new XElement(a + "pPr", 
                                    new XElement(a + "defRPr")
                                    ),
                                new XElement(a +  "endParaRPr", new XAttribute ("lang", "en-US"))
                                )
                            );




        using (XmlReader xmlReader = xml.CreateReader())
        {

           XmlNode  newNode = doc.ReadNode(xmlReader);
            //node.AppendChild(newNode);
            node.InsertAfter(newNode, InsertAfter);
        }
```